# d3 nesting two value as key value pairs

Tags: d3.js, nested

I have a csv file which I converted to an object:

```
[object Object] {
key: "2020-07-09",
values: [[object Object] {
cases: "49174",
date: "2020-07-09",
deaths: "1068",
fips: "01",
state: "Alabama"
}
}
```

I want an output of this object as a nest, something like this:

```
key: "2020-07-09",
perstate: {
"Alabama" : "49174"
}
```

I am not aware how to convert two values into a key value pair

Answer (score 0):

Say the object is in an array, called `data`.

```js
data.map(d => ({
    key: d.key,
    perstate: {
        [d.values.state]: d.values.cases
    }
}))
```

We use an ES6 arrow function for conciseness, putting the object literal in paranteses to indicate that the function returns an object.

To compute the key, we use [ES6 computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names). This allows us to get the value at `values.state` and use it as the key.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working, I get no error, but also console.log prints nothing

Comment: When I remove all the code, and do console.log(d); it prints nothing, you can check out this jsbin: https://jsbin.com/jagacuz/edit?js,console,output

Comment: The objects in data[1] in your code don't have the same structure. Instead it looks like this:
{
  cases: "1",
  county: "Snohomish",
  date: "2020-01-21",
  deaths: "0",
  fips: "53061",
  state: "Washington"
}
So you can do:

data.map(d => ({
    key: d.key,
    perstate: {
        [d.state]: d.cases
    }
}))